# Django: problem with assignment of the ForeignKey

Tags: django

I want to update the database records from the Pandas DataFrame, and I faced an issue with the ForeignKey.

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    try:
        person = Person.obejcts.get(id_no=r['ID Number'])
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"{r['ID Number']} does not exist in the database")
        continue
    t = Task.objects.get_or_create(no=r['Task_no'],
                                   defaults={'area': r['Area'],
                                             'person': person})
    if not t[1]:
        t[0].area = r['Area']
        t[0].person = person  # Error is on this line
        t[0].save()
```

I got an error saying "Task.person" must be a "Person" instance. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this error raised at the `t = Task.object.get_or_create(...)` line?

Comment: nope, on the line t[0].person = person

Comment: There are no two different `Person` classes in your project? Doesn't the error says exactly *what* you assigned to it? Most of the time the error is,  "Can not assign a ... on the ..., must be a ..."

Comment: @Marek is this the real code "Person.obejcts"? I mean obejcts.

Comment: OK, I've found the issue. Incidentally, I added a coma at the end of the line above. This was a reason for the error :)

Comment: @Marek: ah yes, then you assigned a singleton tuple that has wrapped the person.